# ionic cordova facebook plugin duplicate resources

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i am trying to use cordova-plugin-facebook-connect with my ionic angular app using cordova. when i try to build it for android i get

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [string/fb_app_id] myapp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/facebookconnect.xml  [string/fb_app_id] myapp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  [string/fb_app_name] myapp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/facebookconnect.xml        [string/fb_app_name] /myapp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

i have searched quite a bit and find no solution. i tried to delete the manual entries from the strings.xml which are common to facebookconnect.xml but still i get the same error.

ionic info is like

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.13
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 1.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v14.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 7.24.0
   OS         : macOS Monterey
   Xcode      : Xcode 13.1 Build version 13A1030d
```